# S3 bucket 'BlockPublicACL' Setting

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, aws-cloudformation

I was reviewing a CF template where I see that 'BlockPublicACL' is set to False but all the other parameters such as 'IgnorePublicAcls', 'BlockPublicPolicy' and 'RestrictPublicBuckets' is set to True.

Now once deployed should this Bucket be Public as the 'BlockPublicACL' is set to False or would this bucket be not public as all the other parameters are set to true and hence these would override the 'BlockPublicACL' setting ?

```
  BucketInfra:
    Type: AWS::S3::Bucket
    Properties:
      AccessControl: BucketOwnerFullControl 
      BucketName: !Sub '${Environment}-file'
      PublicAccessBlockConfiguration:
        BlockPublicAcls: false   
        IgnorePublicAcls: true
        BlockPublicPolicy: true
        RestrictPublicBuckets: true
```

Answer (score 0):

A "public bucket" typically means that there is a Bucket Policy in place that grants anonymous access to objects in the bucket. In your case, it only permits Public ACLs, which are settings on individual objects. If an object ACL is set to 'public', then **the object is public** (but not the whole bucket).

The setting of S3 Block Public Access itself doesn't make the bucket public, but it might (or might not) block the ability to make objects, or the whole bucket, public.